# Using spring + jpa + hibernate but can't persist entity and never throws exception , tests passed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

I've been testing for a long time and searching for hours. Since there' re some similar questions, but after trying, it still doesn't work , I am using spring MVC and jpa with hibernate to set up a base project, but the problem is I cannot persist entity into database when I put it into jetty. What's strange is that the Junit tests are passed.

Here is the essential code.

web.xml

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/controller.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

db-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- DBCP DataSource -->
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" id="dataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/spring" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <!-- JPA EntityManagerFactory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Persistence Context Annotated -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"
        id="persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <!-- Transaction -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

persistence.xml(in META-INF folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="persist" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion"
                value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Person.java (entity bean)

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // ..

}
```

PersonDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class PersonDaoImpl implements PersonDao {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public Person persist(Person person) {
        entityManager.persist(person);
        return person;
    }

    // ...

}
```

PersonServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

    private PersonDao personDao;

    @Inject
    public void setPersonDao(PersonDao personDao) {
        this.personDao = personDao;
    }

    public Person create(Person person) {
        return personDao.persist(person);
    }

    // @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public Person save(Person person) {
        return personDao.merge(person);
    }

    // ...

}
```

PersonController.java

```
@Controller
@Scope("prototype")
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

    private PersonService personService;

    @Inject
    public void setPersonService(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView add(@RequestParam("username") String name) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(name);
        System.out.println(name);  // i can get the value
        personService.create(person); // nothing happend... throws no Excp
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("result");
        mav.addObject("val", person.getName());
        return mav;
    }

}
```

PersonControllerTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/test-context.xml")
public class PersonControllerTest {

    private PersonController controller;

    @Inject
    public void setController(PersonController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }


        // the test passed no matter @Transactional or not, if not, the db get the row
    @Test(/*expected = NullPointerException.class*/)
    @Transactional
    public void testAdd() {
//      PersonController controller = new PersonController();
        assertEquals("test", controller.add("test").getModelMap().get("val"));
    }

}
```

Some xml like context and mvc config xml and import declaration are omitted, the servie and dao interface, can anyone help me ?

Comment: Your test uses a different context configuration to that of your application? Are there any differences?

Comment: Just as a design tip, I would avoid class level Transactional annotations. Just put exactly what you need on each method. Also generally service methods should be transactional, not DAO methods. A service method is a group of DAO calls grouped into a single transaction. That said none of this should be causing the issues you have seen.

Comment: you have show_sql = true, do you see the generated inserts?

Comment: @alex the text context configration file just copy from the WEB-INF's location, and there' re the same.

Comment: @alex when i test, the sql shows but when put it into jetty, nothing happend. and i also try put transactional annotation only to Service method or both Dao and Service, but it just not effect.

Comment: @jeff when i test, the sql shows, but in jetty, nothing shows...

Comment: can we see your web.xml? if you haven't registered the ContextLoaderListener your context might not be being loaded in Jetty.

Comment: @Alex i'm sorry i forget to put it here, but now it's been put.

Comment: How is db-context.xml referenced? Is it included in root-context.xml?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Junit should not ( and by default does not ) persist into database.

If you want the data to be persisted in database add this line to your test class.

```
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
```